# How to access native word application progress bar using VSTO wordAddIn 2010 using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word, vsto, progress-bar, add-in

Currently I'm a developing a word addIn using C#. I want to access native word application progress bar using my word addin code. Is there any way to get reference native progress bar object?
Development environment is Visual Studio 2010 using C# 4.0
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The question's a little vague. Are you talking about adding a progress bar to a document, as per Terrance's answer (which would seem like a +very+ odd thing to do, but, what do I know<g>), or do you mean you want to control the progress bar that shows up in the Word status bar at the bottom of the Word window from time to time. If the later, I don't thing there's any what to access that from the Word object model.

Comment: Yes. You are correct @drventure. I want access to the later one. To get access native word progress bar to show my custom progress of some tasks. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Controls.ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.controls.progressbar%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)